# How to select default value for DropDownListFor using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I need to display dropdown text based on DB values. I'm not able to find a solution.

**DB Value:**

```
RolesID  DeptID  UserID
2        1        100
5        2        200
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var gt in Model.RoleList)
{
    <tr>                    
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, new SelectList(Model.Role, "RoleId", "RoleName",@gt.RoleId), new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Plants, new SelectList(Model.Department, "DeptId", "DeptName", @gt.DeptId), new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("deletedet", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Edit-User", AllowCache = true, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith }))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("userId", @gt.UserId)
        <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myTable"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
    }

    </tr>
}
```

**Model.RoleList** - contains list of user role id and department id.

**Model.Role**    - contains list of Roles(master table)

**Question:**

- Is there any other way to display default text for dropdownlist?
- Based on RoleId I have to select RoleName in that dropdown.

This dropdown will load dynamically.

Comment: It also can be done via jquery/javascript i.e $('#dropid').val(2)

Comment: thanks zahid, how to get dropid? its dynamically loading ... when page load i need to display that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `foreach` loop `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, new SelectList(Model.Role, "RoleId", "RoleName",gt.RoleId), new { @class = "form-control" })` never working correctly, because in razor `input/select/textarea` create a unique html `name` attribute.But using `foreach` it can't do this. so use `for` loop or `EditorTemplates` rather than `foreach`.

Other wise you can generate the html but you can't send list of item in your action.

**Example:**

```
@for(var i = 0;i < Model.RoleList.Count;i++)
{
    <tr>
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.RoleList[i].RoleId, new SelectList(Model.Role, "RoleId", "RoleName", Model.RoleList[i].RoleId), new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: wow! awesome. Thank you verymuch Ashiquzzaman

Comment: You are welcome.@SENA